# How can I teleport my snake through the wall with Vector2 in python pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want it to come back from the opposite side of the same direction from the coordinate where the snake passed through the wall.

### this is the part where i define the snake and its direction

```
    def __init__(self):
    self.tail = None
    self.head = None
    self.body = [Vector2(5, 10), Vector2(4, 10), Vector2(3, 10)]
    self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
    self.new_block = False

    self.head_up = pygame.image.load("head_up.png").convert_alpha()
    self.head_down = pygame.image.load("head_down.png").convert_alpha()
    self.head_right = pygame.image.load("head_right.png").convert_alpha()
    self.head_left = pygame.image.load("head_left.png").convert_alpha()

    self.tail_up = pygame.image.load("tail_up.png").convert_alpha()
    self.tail_down = pygame.image.load("tail_down.png").convert_alpha()
    self.tail_right = pygame.image.load("tail_right.png").convert_alpha()
    self.tail_left = pygame.image.load("tail_left.png").convert_alpha()

    self.body_vertical = pygame.image.load("body_vertical.png").convert_alpha()
    self.body_horizontal = pygame.image.load("body_horizontal.png").convert_alpha()

    self.body_tr = pygame.image.load("body_tr.png").convert_alpha()
    self.body_tl = pygame.image.load("body_tl.png").convert_alpha()
    self.body_br = pygame.image.load("body_br.png").convert_alpha()
    self.body_bl = pygame.image.load("body_bl.png").convert_alpha()

    self.crunch_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sound_crunch.wav")
```

### this part is supposed to work correctly but not working

##WINDOW WIDTH and WINDOW HEIGHT in this section show the size of the window

```
    if self.snake.body[0].x > 0 and self.snake.body[0].x != 0:
        self.snake.body[0].x += WINDOW_WIDTH
    if self.snake.body[0].y > 0 and self.snake.body[0].y != 0:
        self.snake.body[0].y += WINDOW_HEIGHT
    if self.snake.body[0].x > WINDOW_WIDTH and self.snake.body[0].x != WINDOW_WIDTH:
        self.snake.body[0].x -= WINDOW_WIDTH
    if self.snake.body[0].y > WINDOW_HEIGHT and self.snake.body[0].y != WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        self.snake.body[0].y -= WINDOW_HEIGHT
    if self.snake.body[0].x == 0:
        self.snake.body[0].x += WINDOW_WIDTH
    if self.snake.body[0].y == 0:
        self.snake.body[0].y += WINDOW_HEIGHT
    if self.snake.body[0].x == WINDOW_WIDTH:
        self.snake.body[0].x = 0
    if self.snake.body[0].y == WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        self.snake.body[0].y = 0

    def move_snake(self):
    if self.new_block:
        body_copy = self.body[:]
        body_copy.insert(0, body_copy[0] + self.direction)
        self.body = body_copy[:]
        self.new_block = False
    else:
        body_copy = self.body[:-1]
        body_copy.insert(0, body_copy[0] + self.direction)
        self.body = body_copy[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to test if `self.snake.body[0].x < 0` and `self.snake.body[0].y < 0` instead of `self.snake.body[0].x > 0` and `self.snake.body[0].y > 0`.
2. Consider the following code:

   ```py
   if x == 0:
       x += WINDOW_WIDTH
   if x == WINDOW_WIDTH:
        x = 0
   ```

   If `x` is 0, the 1st condition is fulfilled and `x` becomes `WINDOW_WIDTH`. But now the 2nd condition is fulfilled and `x` becomes 0 again.

So your code should look something like this:

```py
if self.snake.body[0].x < 0:
    self.snake.body[0].x += WINDOW_WIDTH
else if self.snake.body[0].x >= WINDOW_WIDTH:
    self.snake.body[0].x -= WINDOW_WIDTH

if self.snake.body[0].y < 0:
    self.snake.body[0].y += WINDOW_HEIGHT
else if self.snake.body[0].y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT:
    self.snake.body[0].y -= WINDOW_HEIGHT
```

This code can be further simplified with the `%` (modulo) operator:

<kbd>[[image] replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ContinuousMovement](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ContinuousMovement#main.py)</kbd>

```py
self.snake.body[0].x %= WINDOW_WIDTH
self.snake.body[0].y %= WINDOW_HEIGHT
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    dx = (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel
    dy = (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel
        
    rect.centerx = (rect.centerx + dx) % window.get_width()
    rect.centery = (rect.centery + dy) % window.get_height()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```